# AngularJS select default option according to url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown menu that contains some links for various section of the page. The application is written with AngularJS version 1.4, the dropdown menu does works, but when I enter the page directly through the url in the dropdown menu is always selected the empty voice instead of the correct one. Here' the code:

HTML

```
<select ng-options="menu_voice.name for menu_voice in menu_voices track by menu_voice.url" ng-model='selectedOption' ng-change="changeLink()">
</select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.changeLink = function(){
    $state.go($scope.selectedOption.url);
};

$scope.menu_voices = [
    {
        "url": 'account.company',
        "name": 'Company'
    },
    {
        "url": 'account.billing',
        "name": 'Billing'
    },
    {
        "url": 'account.password',
        "name": 'Password'
    },
    {
        "url": 'account.design',
        "name": 'Design'
    },
    {
        "url": 'account.social',
        "name": 'Social'
    },
    {
        "url": 'account.notifications',
        "name": 'Notifications'
    }
];
```

If I select a voice in the dropdown menu, I go to the correct link with the correct voice selected. But if in the url bar I enter something like:

```
www.myapp.com/account/billing
```

I go to the correct page but in the dropdown menu the selected voice is empty.

How can I solve this?

EDIT after first reply:

I added this:

```
var name = $window.location.pathname;
name = name.substring(9);
name = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);

var url = $window.location.pathname.substring(1).replace(/\//g, '.');

$scope.getSelectedFromUrl = function(){
    $scope.selectedOption = {"name": name, "url": url};
};
```

If I print in the console

```
console.log($scope.selectedOption);
```

I get the correct object, e.g:

```
Object {name: "Design", url: "account.design"}
```

In the html I simply added the ng-init:

```
 <select ng-options="menu_voice.name for menu_voice in menu_voices track by menu_voice.url" ng-model='selectedOption' ng-change="changeLink()" ng-init="selectedOption = getSelectedFromUrl()">
 </select>
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: Can you give us a short sample?

Comment: What do you mean by short sample?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ng-init directive to call a function that parses the route and matches it to an item from the voices array. Then set the selectedOption model to that array item, which will set the select option.

```
ng-init="selectedOption = getSelectedFromURL()"
```